# Converting a slice of slices in Go?

Tags: go

How do I convert this slice of byte slices

```
[[105 100] [49]]
```

to slice of strings?

I tried

```
sliceOfStrings := []string(sliceOfByteSlices.([][]byte))
```

and got a

```
invalid type assertion: values.([][]byte) (non-interface type []interface {} on left)
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/6L6xsrWa2X

Comment: You can't convert it in one step as you expect it to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You should do for loop, but you can cheat a-little using std lib

```
byt := bytes.Join(a, []byte(sep))
str := strings.Split(string(byt), sep)
```

here is working example https://play.golang.org/p/QzySUsRMg6

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a for-loop like so:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var res []string
    arr := [][]byte{{105, 100}, {49}}

    for _, b := range arr {
        res = append(res, string(b))
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Test here: http://play.golang.org/p/el4YXfFZpM